kvm: How is iommu PCI passthrough of an nvidia graphcis card experienced?
I have a KVM host with two graphics cards: An onboard and an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080.
Assuming I eventually get PCI passthrough of the Nvidia graphics card to a ubuntu guest working, will it behave like these assumptions? :

If I connect a monitor to built-in HDMI connection, I'll see the host, and if I connect the monitor to the Nvidia graphics card I'll see the guest.

There won't be a "spice" display to use in virt-manager. (It would be nice, but I'm assuming not...)


By default any USB devices such as keyboard, mouse, webcam etc. I attach to the physical machine will go to the host, but I can forward them as USB devices to the guest. And then as long as the guest is running, they'll be connected to the guest, and when I stop the guest, they'll be re-attached to the host.
When I have forwarded USB devices: keyboard, mouse and webcam, I'll be able to use the VM as my primary desktop.

Is that the essence of how it behaves when it all works?
What am I trying to do?
I have new machine that I want to use as both a home server (NAS, docker, KVM) and as a desktop machine. The easiest would of course just to use one Ubuntu desktop OS and export NFS, samba, printers etc. from it and run docker and KVM on it too.
My experience from the past is that one shared OS makes it painful to upgrade. The desktop aspect of that one shared machine is chaotic, while the "home server" aspect is more static, and I'd like to be able to upgrade one without the other. Hence the idea of hosting the desktop in a KVM VM with PCI passthrough of the Nvidia graphics card.
I may even want to use a headless NixOS server for the "home server" aspect.
Alternatives considered
Perhaps I should just keep it simple and use a single OS for everything, perhaps pushing as much as possible into docker containers.
Or perhaps reverse this, and have the desktop machine install on the metal, and then have a KVM "home server" and forward disks, printers, etc. to that machine?
